# Updating MXD layer definitionQuery in arcpy is very slow

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2, mxd

The code segment below has been extracted from a larger project.  In short, I have an `MXD` which I want to generate multiple PDFs based on different criteria.  The code below works.  It loops through each of the layers within the MXD and updates the `definitionQuery` and the results are fine.  On my desktop, the part of the code that sets the `definitionQuery` takes about 2 seconds, but the published code on the server takes over 40 seconds.  Since that bit of code is called for each item in `layer_parameter_list`, the time of the report jumps from about a minute to multiple minutes.

When I update the `defintionQuery`, does the `MXD` get written to the drive?  Does it re-filter the data then?  On the server, the scratch is on a shared drive which could explain why it is slower.  What can I do to improve performance?  Can I tell the `MXD` not to be written?  If the re-filtering is occurring, can I disable that until all `definitionQuery`s have been updated for all layers?

```
def function_that_iterates_over_data_and_generates_pdf_pages_from_mxd(mxd, extent):
    layer_parameter_list = [
        # field 1,    field 2,  field 3
        ['Company1', 'Value X',    'Value 1'],
        ['Company1', 'Value Y',    'Value 2'],

        ['Company2', 'Value X',    'Value 1'],
        ['Company2', 'Value Y',    'Value 2'],
    ]

    layer_queries = [
        ['layer_1', """"FIELD_1"='{0}' and "FIELD_2"='{1}'""",
                    """"FIELD_1"='{0}'' and "FIELD_2"='{1}'"""],
        ['layer_2', """"FIELD_2"='{1}' and "FIELD_3"='{2}'""",
                    """"FIELD_2"='{1}'' and "FIELD_3"='{2}'"""],
        ['layer_3', """"FIELD_1"='{0}' and "FIELD_3"='{2}'""",
                    """"FIELD_1"='{0}'' and "FIELD_3"='{2}'"""],
    ]

    dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)

    lyr_dict = {}
    for df in dfs:
        # Take opportunity to zoom each Dataframe as we build our
        # dictionary
        df.extent = extent
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
            if lyr.isFeatureLayer or lyr.isServiceLayer:
                lyr_dict[lyr.name, df.name] = lyr

    for (page_number, query_parameters) in enumerate(layer_parameter_list):
        # this block takes ~2 seconds on my desktop, but 40+ seconds on the server
        for (dfi, df) in enumerate(dfs):
            for layer_query in layer_queries:
                criteria = layer_query[dfi + 1].format(*query_parameters)
                arcpy.AddMessage("Criteria: " + criteria)#this was the problem line
                lyr = lyr_dict[layer_query[0], df.name]
                lyr.definitionQuery = criteria

        file_name = 'Page_{0}'.format('%02s' % page_number)
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, file_name)
```

EDIT: added back in the AddMessage line which was the cause of the slow down.

Comment: It looks like the 'something's changed on this layer' event is fired and the 'map' is refreshed for each change in the definition query. Here's something in java that might help https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_events.html look here to turn them off while you change their def query and turn them back on again http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17136-Turn-layers-off-w-arcpy.mapping

Comment: Thank you for the notes, but they don't seem to be what I need.  The problem happens on the server, not the client, so there is not visible window to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was **not** related to the `definitionQuery` at all.  It was the logging that was killing my performance.  For my example code, I had stripped out the logging for the sake of space.  Apparently INFO level logging is very slow.